# How to implement NativeAdExpressView RecyclerView and Volley Together?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, android-volley

I am working on an android app which fetch data from JSON Url and Show it into Recyclerview. I want to add native ads between items so i add NativeExpressAdView into Recyclerview by Following this tutorial [Git Hub Tutorial](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/nativeexpressrecyclerviewexample). 
I am getting error on onBindViewHolder()

Error that i am getting is

ava.lang.ClassCastException: com.sctar.moviestime.myRecycler.GetDataAdapter cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
                                                                          at com.sctar.moviestime.myRecycler.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:119

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
private  List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;
private static final int MOVIE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE=0;
private static final int SCROLL_AD_VIEW=1;
public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems)
{
    super();
    this.mContext=context;
    this.mRecyclerViewItems=mRecyclerViewItems;
}

public class MoviesItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public  TextView movieNameTV,movieGenreTV;
    public YouTubeThumbnailView videoThumbnail;
    public String movie_url="";

    public MoviesItemViewHolder(View mView) {
        super(mView);
        movieNameTV=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.movieNameTV);
        movieGenreTV=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.movieGenre);
        videoThumbnail=(YouTubeThumbnailView)mView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailView1);
        videoThumbnail.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEV_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(movie_url);
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                        youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
    }
}
public class NativeExpressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public NativeExpressViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return  mRecyclerViewItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position%HomeFragment.ITEMS_PER_AD==0)?SCROLL_AD_VIEW:MOVIE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case SCROLL_AD_VIEW:
            View scroll_ad_layout=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.scroll_ad_layout,parent,false);
            return  new NativeExpressViewHolder(scroll_ad_layout);
        case MOVIE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            //Fall through
        default:
            View movie_item_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_card, parent, false);
            return new MoviesItemViewHolder(movie_item_view);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    switch (viewType) {
        case SCROLL_AD_VIEW:
                NativeExpressViewHolder nativeExpressViewHolder = (NativeExpressViewHolder) holder;
                NativeExpressAdView nativeExpressAdView= (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
                ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup) nativeExpressViewHolder.itemView;
                adCardView.removeAllViews();
            if (adCardView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                adCardView.removeAllViews();
            }
            if (nativeExpressAdView.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) nativeExpressAdView.getParent()).removeView(nativeExpressAdView);
            }
            adCardView.addView(nativeExpressAdView);
            break;
        case MOVIE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            //Fall Through
            default:
            MoviesItemViewHolder moviesItemViewHolder = (MoviesItemViewHolder) holder;
            GetDataAdapter cardItem = (GetDataAdapter) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
            moviesItemViewHolder.movieNameTV.setText(cardItem.getName());
            moviesItemViewHolder.movieGenreTV.setText(cardItem.getGenre());
            moviesItemViewHolder.movie_url = cardItem.getMovie_url();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

HomeFragment.java class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
String GET_JSON_DATA_URL="http://sctar.com/moviestime/admin/getMovie.php?page=";
String JSON_NAME="movie_name";
String JSON_GENRE="movie_genre";
String JSON_URL="movie_url";
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
TextView movieName,play_movieName;
EqualizerView equalizerView;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private int pageNumber=1;
GetDataAdapter cardItem;
private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;
    public static final int ITEMS_PER_AD=8;
    private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT=150;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID="ca-app-pub-1094536469217749/8160042117";
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);
    setRetainInstance(true);


    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.homeRV);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    movieName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.movieNameTV);
    play_movieName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.play_movieNameTV);

    //Specify a Layout Manager
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    mRecyclerViewItems=new ArrayList<>();

    progressBar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    equalizerView=(EqualizerView)view.findViewById(R.id.equalizer_view);
    //Update RecyclerView Items
    //addData();

    youTubePlayerFragment=YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment,youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, final int position, View v) {


            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEV_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer yPlayer, boolean b) {
                    if(!b)
                    {
                        cardItem=(GetDataAdapter)mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
                        String movie_url=cardItem.getMovie_url();
                        yPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                        yPlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
                        //yPlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
                        yPlayer.loadVideo(movie_url);
                        yPlayer.play();
                        equalizerView.animateBars();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                }

            });
            youTubePlayerFragment.onDestroy();
              }
            });

            //Get Data from the Server
    addData();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if(isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                    addData();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
                if(isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView))
                    addData();
            }
        });
    }

 //   addData();

    //Load Native and Banner Ads
    addNativeScrollAds();
    setupAndLoadNativeAds();
    addBannerAds(view);

    return view;
}
    public void addData()
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(json_web_call(pageNumber));
        pageNumber++;
    }


    private void addNativeScrollAds(){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(mRecyclerViewItems.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for(int i=0;i<mRecyclerViewItems.size();i+=ITEMS_PER_AD){
            NativeExpressAdView adView=new NativeExpressAdView(this.getActivity());
            adView.setAdSize(new AdSize(320,150));
            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            mRecyclerViewItems.add(i,adView);
        }
    }
public void setupAndLoadNativeAds(){
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    final float scale=getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    // Set the ad size and ad unit ID for each Native Express ad in the items list.
                    for (int i = 0; i <mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
                            final NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(i);
                            CardView cardView=(CardView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scrollAdCard);
                            final int adWidth = cardView.getWidth() - cardView.getPaddingLeft()
                                    - cardView.getPaddingRight();
                            AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int) (adWidth / scale), NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT);
                            adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
                    }
                    // Load the first Native Express ad in the items list.
                    loadNativeExpressAd(8);
                }
            });
        }

    private void loadNativeExpressAd(final int index){

        if(index>=mRecyclerViewItems.size()){
            return;
        }
        Object item=mRecyclerViewItems.get(index);
        if(!(item instanceof NativeExpressAdView)){
            throw new ClassCastException("Expected Item at Index "+index+" to be a Native Express Adview");
        }
        final NativeExpressAdView adView=(NativeExpressAdView)item;
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                   loadNativeExpressAd(index+ITEMS_PER_AD);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                Log.e("HomeFragment","The Previous native ad failed to load, attempting to load next ad in item list");
                loadNativeExpressAd(index+ITEMS_PER_AD);
            }
        });
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(mRecyclerViewItems.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void addBannerAds(View view){
        AdView bannerAdView=(AdView)view.findViewById(R.id.bannerAdview1);
        AdRequest bannerAdRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("cph1701-a17bc212").build();
        bannerAdView.loadAd(bannerAdRequest);
    }
public JsonArrayRequest json_web_call(int pageNumber)
{
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_URL+String.valueOf(pageNumber), new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    //jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            json_parse_data(response);
           progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
    return jsonArrayRequest;
    //requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
    //requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}

public void json_parse_data(JSONArray array)
{
    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
    {
        try  {
              JSONObject json=array.getJSONObject(i);
              String name=json.getString(JSON_NAME);
              String genre=json.getString(JSON_GENRE);
              String movie_url=json.getString(JSON_URL);
              GetDataAdapter menuItem=new GetDataAdapter(name,genre,movie_url);
              //if(i%ITEMS_PER_AD!=0)
              mRecyclerViewItems.add(menuItem);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this.getContext(),mRecyclerViewItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()!=0){
            int lastVisibleItem=((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if(lastVisibleItem!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItem==recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

}

GetDataAdapter Class

```
public class GetDataAdapter {
 int id;
 String name;
String genre;
String movie_url;
public GetDataAdapter(){
    //Default Constructor
}
public GetDataAdapter(String name,String genre,String movie_url){
    this.name=name;
    this.genre=genre;
    this.movie_url=movie_url;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String getMovie_url() {
    return movie_url;
}

public void setMovie_url(String movie_url) {
    this.movie_url = movie_url;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first problem should be the lack of an `=` sign in the `addNativeScrollAds` method of `HomeFragment` class, in the **for** cycle.

You should add it like this (read the inline comment):

```
for (int i=0; i<=/*i added equals here*/mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i+=ITEMS_PER_AD){
    NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(this.getActivity());
    adView.setAdSize(new AdSize(320,150));
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mRecyclerViewItems.add(i,adView);
}
```

The second problem should be in the `setupAndLoadNativeAds` method, where the for cycle lack the `=` in the exact same place.

Let me know if this solves the problem

Comment: Thank You for instant help. I am handling both views. Let me share code in detail.

Comment: I have updated details. Kindly let me know if you can help Sir. Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: ohkk Sure Sir. :)

Comment: @JitanderVerma i've updated my answer, try and let me know if it works

Comment: Ok sir,  thank you. let me make updation to my code. I will let you know.

Comment: Hello Sir, Its not working still. I think = sign will throw array index execption also.

Comment: But in the tutorial you followed it's present : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/nativeexpressrecyclerviewexample/MainActivity.java#L102 so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Yes, I also checked. Actually in the github example, items are not dynamically added. where as .. I am trying to load items from MySql database. Threrefore, I think, NativeAd shows at wrong index

Comment: Google Ans: make sure you are calling the ad requests on the proper index of the array. If you are changing the items in the list dynamically, then an ad received might make it to the wrong index, which might not contain the original ad view that the request was made for.

Also, I could see that you have posted this question in several threads. I would like you to continue the discussion in this thread from now on if you still continue to have issues.

Comment: :( Still not getting anything

Comment: Its Working Now. All I do is, Call Methods inside onResponse() methods which were used to load ads in Recyclerview.